# Why can't I cast a more derived generic type to a less derived generic type?

Tags: c#

I have the following two interfaces

```
public class IMessage
{
}


public interface IListener<TMessage>  where TMessage : IMessage
{
    void ProcessMessage(TMessage message);
}
```

I need a specific Listener To implement `IListener<TMessage>` that takes a specific type of message

```
public class DeleteEmployeeMessage : IMessage
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
}
```

Now I implement my Listener like so

```
public class DeleteEmployeeListener : IListener<DeleteEmployeeMessage>
{
    public void ProcessMessage(DeleteEmployeeMessage)
    {
        // CODE HERE
    }

}
```

Now I want to create an object of `DeleteEmployeeListener` and cast it to generic interface type;

```
IListener<IMessage> listenerInterfaceObj;
DeleteEmployeeListener concreteMessageListener = new DeleteEmployeeListener();

listenerInterfaceObj = (IListener<IMessage>) concreteMessageListener; // this line crashes at runtime
```

I get the following runtime error

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type
> 'DeleteEmployeeListener' to type 'IListener`1[IMessage]'.'

Why is that? Why can't I cast a `Cat` to an `Animal`?

Comment: Should you be able to cast a `List<Animal>` to `IList<object>`? How might that relate to your situation?

Comment: You're not casting `Cat` to `Animal`. `DeleteEmployeeListener` implements `IListener<DeleteEmployeeMessage>`. It does not implement `IListener<IMessage>`. That's why you can't cast `DeleteEmployeeMessage` to `IListener<IMessage>`

Comment: `listenerInterfaceObj` is an object that can process all kinds of `IMessage`s, because its declared type is `IListener<IMessage>`, but `concreteMessageListener` can only process `DeleteEmployeeMessage`. Therefore, `IListener<DeleteEmplyeeMessage>` is not a kind of `IListener<IMessage>`.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/creating-variant-generic-interfaces may be worth a read (may or may not be useful in your context).

Comment: If you had `IFruit`, `Apple : IFruit`, and `Banana: IFruit`, then if you could cast `List<Apple>` to `List<IFruit>` you'd be able to add a `Banana` to a list that can only take `Apple`. Boom. Run-time error.

Comment: Just as an aside, I presume you mean `public interface IMessage` (not `public class IMessage`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider we introduce messages and listeners for creating employees:

```
public class CreateMessage : IMessage {
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
}

public class CreateEmployeeListener : IListener<CreateMessage> {
    public void ProcessMessage(CreateMessage message) {
    }
}

// Later...
var listener = (IListener<IMessage>) new DeleteEmployeeListener();
IMessage createMessage = new CreateMessage();
listener.ProcessMessage(createMessage); // What happens here?
```

Although `createMessage` is an `IMessage`, `DeleteEmployeeListener` can't handle a `CreateMessage`.

In the case of your `Ilistener` interface, the generic type is contravariant, meaning the "input" types are generic. This means you can pass a **more** specific type, but not less.

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance